# Chrome Window without Searchbar and Menubar

Tags: html

**Is there a way to open a Chrome window without the search bar, menu bar, and all that stuff?** I have tried all of the tips coding sites give you, but none of them worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can open link in new *popup window* using JavaScript:

```
window.open("http://www.google.com/", "_blank", "width=500,height=500");
```

Just change address and window dimesions.
(It won't work if popups are blocked)

[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/m5tLd4d1/)

Comment: Thanks! That really helped me!